# Travel service given to guest by hotel called?

Tags: phrases

Is there any specific term for the travel service provided by hotels when they pick up their guests from the airport say - and when they drop off the guests again when they check out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Airport Transfer* is a commonly used term.

Comment: @tchrist: I live in India and it's more or less standard usage here. Relatively uncommon is *Airport Shuttle,* but thats used too. AFAICT, *Airport Transfer* is used in NZ and UK too- from what a glance at the first page of google results tells me. http://www.google.co.in/#q=Airport+Transfer

Comment: Interesting. _Shuttle_ would be more common in the U.S. Incidentally, this might have been a good [ell.se] question.

Answer (score 7):

*Shuttle bus service* ([Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_bus_service))

> A shuttle bus service is a public transport bus service designed to quickly transport people between two points. Such a bus will 'shuttle' backwards and forwards between the two points, normally without any intermediate stops and with a high frequency of trips. Such services are often designed to serve specific customers, such as hotels, attractions, park and ride routes or airport bus services.

Answer (score 4):

Terms like *courtesy van* (or *[courtesy car](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/courtesy+car)* or *vehicle*) are sometimes used.  According to  dictionary.reference.com, a courtesy car is “a limousine or van provided by a hotel, airline, etc., for free transportation over a fixed route, as between an airport and a hotel.”

Also consider *airport shuttle*, which is similar to previously suggested  *shuttle bus service* except for being airport-specific and – in recent years – more [commonly used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=airport+shuttle%2Cshuttle+bus%2Cshuttle+bus+service&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)  than  *shuttle bus service*.